# Korn Shell, won't read file without cp?

Tags: ksh

To display text from a file do you have to use the command CP.

In my first snippet this is what worked fine:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#

count=$# #number of arguments

echo "Please enter filename to open:"
read file
cp $file temp
cat temp
echo "bye"
```

If i tried this command it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#

count=$# #number of arguments

echo "Please enter filename to open:"
read temp
#cp $file temp
cat temp
echo "bye"
```

It simply can't pick up the file in the second example. Does CP really need to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 cat temp
```

Tries to read a file called `temp`.

To read the file pointed to by the variable `temp`, use:

```
  cat $temp
```

You already do this correctly in your first example when you reference the variable `file` using `$file`.